# How to use svg sprite in react?

Tags: typescript, svg, sprite, react-tsx

Hello I search many questions in stackoverflow about this issue but nothing help me.
I have svg srite

```
<svg width="25" height="25" >
  <symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50" id="dota-icon">
    <path d="M46,8V6c0-0.552-0.447-1-1-1h-4c-0.396,0-0.714,0.026-1,0.1V5c0-0.552-0.447-1-1-1h-6c-1.734,0-2.361,0.984-2.729,2h-0.812 C29.226,5.689,29,5.286,29,5c0-0.552-0.447-1-1-1h-7c-0.511,0-0.94,0.393-0.995,0.9C19.982,5.11,19.557,6,18.896,6h-2.74 c-0.065-0.077-0.159-0.22-0.24-0.403C15.756,5.234,15.396,5,15,5H5C4.447,5,4,5.448,4,6v8c0,2.823,0.825,6.397,0.999,7.118 l-0.008,1.515l-0.678,0.641C4.113,23.462,4,23.725,4,24v4c0,0.266,0.105,0.52,0.293,0.707L5,29.414v4.424l-0.948,2.846 c-0.061,0.181-0.068,0.374-0.021,0.559l0.929,3.718l-0.907,2.724c-0.103,0.305-0.051,0.641,0.137,0.901C4.377,44.846,4.679,45,5,45 h14c0.266,0,0.52-0.105,0.707-0.293l0.09-0.09C20.328,45.343,21.067,46,22,46h3c0.736,0,1.38-0.321,1.947-0.605 C27.335,45.2,27.736,45,28,45h5c0.266,0,0.52-0.105,0.707-0.293l0.243-0.243c0.063,0.08,0.123,0.159,0.182,0.235 C34.623,45.339,35.13,46,36,46h5c0.553,0,1-0.447,1-1v-0.719l2.758,0.688c0.299,0.077,0.616,0.007,0.86-0.184 c0.243-0.19,0.384-0.483,0.382-0.793c-0.001-0.098-0.063-9.91,0-14.98c0.003-0.27-0.103-0.529-0.293-0.72L45,27.586V23 c0-0.265-0.105-0.52-0.293-0.707l-0.49-0.49l0.605-1.21l0.885-0.885C45.895,19.52,46,19.265,46,19l-0.015-5.01 c0-0.081-0.01-0.161-0.029-0.24l-0.896-3.632l0.835-1.67C45.964,8.309,46,8.155,46,8z M34.089,12l3.044,2l-1.015,6L28,14L34.089,12z M15,38l-4-3l2-7l8,8L15,38z M36.2,37h-4.667L11,12.926L14.733,12L39,30.518L36.2,37z"></path>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

I tried to use it like

```
 <use
 xlinkHref="../../img/svg-sprite.svg#icon-dota"
/>
```

or

```
    <svg width="10" height="10">
        <use xlinkHref="../../img/svg-sprite.svg#icon-dota"></use>
      </svg>
```

Then I tried to import as ReactComponent, but I got this problem
**Cannot find module "../../img/svg-sprite.svg" or associated type declarations.**
I found solution

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      //...
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      },
    ],
  },
  //...
};
```

But is does not help too.
Please help me to use sprite in React